# Convert list of image URLs into viewable images (wrap with HTML img tags)

Tags: html, linux, parsing, text

I have a file containing nothing but URLs (each on it's own line) to some images I had in a blogpost, I want to convert this file to be a list of HTML `img` tags, then add `<html>` at the top and `</html>` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, the `-i` means "inline", this will edit and save the file you provide (remove the `-i` to test)

```
sed -i -e 's/^/<img src="/' path_to_your_file
sed -i -e 's/$/">/' path_to_your_file
```

then edit the file to prefix with `<html>` and postfix with `</html>`
(TODO: please someone enhance this last section of my answer)